# jQuery 1.5.1 vs. Prototype causes Unresponsive Script in FireFox

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

After upgrading to jQuery 1.5.1, I get the Unresponsive Script warning in FireFox.

Nothing else was changed, only jQuery upgrade from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1. If I debug the script, and see the stacktrace I can see that the code that causes the unresponsive script is quite simple:

```
$("div.activityItems[gid='-1']").children().attr("disabled", "disabled")
```

Has anyone else experienced similar issues, in regard to jQuery 1.5.1?

**UPDATE**

I've localized the conflict to be between JQuery 1.5.1 and Prototype. Upgrading Prototype to v. 1.7 results in obvious conflicts:

```
$(document.body).keydown is not a function
$.fn is undefined
```

Any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: How many children does that div have? Are they all elements that can take a `disabled` attribute? NB: It's probably unrelated, but using self invented, invalid attributes like your `gid`, is something I personally would avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re the update:

Keep in mind both libraries define the function `$`. Are you using jQueries [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)? I'm not familiar with Prototype, so you should check if it has a similar feature.

And it's probably obvious and dumb, but I'll say it anyway: Don't use both libraries. They share basically the same features, so you are no only asking for problems, but also bloating your page if you use both.

Comment: Yeah, I made some ugly modifications to the prototype library, replacing $( with $p( - which fixes the conflict. Unfortunately, we have some legacy code that uses Prototype. We don't want to use noConflict, since this requires us to replace all $() selectors, which we don't want to do.

The modified Prototype trick takes care of the conflicts, now we just have a few things that stopped working, but that should be possible to fix.

Basically, we want to get rid of Prototype but we are limited to doing damage control for the upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

Stack traces are not really useful in cases like that as "unresponsive script" just means a JavaScript was running for an excessively long time and thus rendering the browser unresponsive.

So you need to check your code for long or even infinite loops, excessive recursion depths and similar things which might take a long time to execute.

Comment: Ok, but the code hasn't changed. Worked in jQuery 1.4.2, doesn't work in 1.5.1.

Comment: Then some more code would be useful... or even a testcase on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce in jsFiddle, but if I could this question would of course be more thorough. I just wanted to ask if anyone else has experienced anything similar.